# How to create long string of bytes in big-endian format

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, endianness, struct.pack

I'm trying to create a 16 bytes string on the wire in Big-Endian format. As you can see I'm ending-up with Little-Endian; where prepended 0's are at the end.

```
>>> import struct
>>> auth = "{0:<16}".format(1437722681) 
>>> authenticator = struct.pack("16s",bytes(auth,"utf-8")) 
>>> print (authenticator)
b'1437722681      '
```

I would like to create a code where I can have prepended values at the beginning, something like below:

```
>>> print (authenticator)
b'      1437722681'
```

Comment: What language or environment are you using?  The way this would be done in Java is not portable to all other languages.

Comment: I'm using Python3. Code excerpts are from python interpreter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that change of the following line did the trick.

```
"{0:>16}.format(...)
```